# How to correctly write SQL query for JOIN from the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table in which I have notes to the customer.

These notes can be public to all administration users, but the user can only have a private note for himself.

I tried this query, but the result is 0 lines.

```sql
select c0.*
from customer_note as c0
       left join customer_note as c1 on c0.id = c1.id
where c0.private = 0
and (c1.private = 1 and c1.user_id = 2)
```

This query does exactly what I need, but I'd like to avoid the UNION clause.

```sql
select c0.*
from customer_note as c0
       left join customer_note as c1 on c0.id = c1.id
where c0.private = 0

union

select c1.*
from customer_note as c1
where c1.private = 1
  and c1.user_id = 2
```

table structure:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`note` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`create_stamp` datetime NOT NULL,
`private` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`state` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you simply mean something like:

```
select c0.*
from   customer_note as c0
where  c0.private = 0
    or (c0.private = 1 and c0.user_id = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant ... I'm thinking complicated.

Answer (score 0):

c0 and c1 are the same rows. you expect that for user_id = 2 the private flag has to be 0 in c0 and 1 in c1 which is impossible because it is the same row.

remove one of the private=.. conditions and it will work but might return more rows than expected